# How to run Grunt command from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, gruntjs

I have written Grunt task for minifying and combining multiple scripts and styles in each single file for Visual Studio ASP.NET project.

This grunt task can be run on project solution directory as follows and works fine.

1. Open command Prompt (cmd.exe)
2. Go to Project directory `cd /Visual/Studio/Project/Directory/`
3. Run grunt command line `grunt`

It works fine. I need that this task should be run automatically in screen behind (or output window) when I save any `.js` or `.css` file in that project directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Till now I have succeeded in running the above process using a shortcut as follows:

## I. Add External Tool

1. Go to `External Tools` under `Tools` menu in Visual Studio
2. Click on `Add`, write following details:

   ```
   Title: Grunt  
   Command : C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
   Arguments: /k grunt
   Initial Directory: $(ProjectDir)

   Optionally, check **Use Output Directory** option.
   ```

   [image]
3. Move the item to top in `External Tools` Click `OK`

## II. Add shortcut to External Command

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80cb6ks3(v=vs.100).aspx)

1. Go to `Tools` menu, click `Options`.
2. Select Keyboard on the Environment page.
3. In the Show commands containing list, type Tools.
4. In the Command names list, locate the appropriate External Command n
   entry.
5. Put the cursor in the Press shortcut keys box, and then press the
   keys you want to assign to the external tool.
6. Click Assign

So, now the grunt task can be run from a shortcut. **But still I could not make it run automatically on saving a file(.js/.css).**

Comment: Thanks for this! What does the `/k` part of the argument do?

Comment: @Jimmy /k: `Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables` https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Answer (score 4):

VS now includes the "Task Runner" extension. It will automatically detect if you have a `gruntfile.js` in your project and show tasks from it. You can also use its UI to bind tasks to "Before Build" "After Build" "Project open" etc.

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt595751.aspx